# Does Lucene search engine supports HTTP requests

Tags: rest, lucene, httprequest

I am trying to learn Lucene,as of now i see how to build queries but not sure how to query it. Like Solr does Lucene search engine supports HTTP requests - REST calls?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802467/has-lucene-search-engine-not-solr-rest-api-for-querying-the-indexed-content) too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Lucene is a search library, not an HTTP server. Solr is the search server Apache created using their Lucene library.